# Floating bullets to the right but keeping the "left to right order" intact

Tags: css

I have a list that I floated to the right:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghDdm/6/

The problem with this is that my list is now "out-of-order", that is it should read:

link 1 | link 2 | link 3...

instead of

link 6 | link 5 | link 4

I tried using text-align: right on the .box class but this doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3):

You're telling each list item to float right, instead of just the list.  You need the list to float right, but each list item to float left.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghDdm/11/

Comment: Seriously you are a lifesaver. Thanks!